# Android Development general question

Tags: java, android

I'm learning how to write Android apps and am having the same issues I've had with learning languages in general - data types are impossible to deal with!

Why is it so hard to convert data from one type to another??  Why does everything use complex, custom data sets?  The issue I'm trying to figure out right now is a good example:  Android Location Services API.  When I finally get the location data from Android its in this special Location type that doesn't convert to a basic string at all.  Using the built in types like whatever.getLatitude() doesn't work either. Again, why is it so hard for API/OS to provide a simple conversion routine??

Example apps tend to never help, even if I get one compiled it still crashes.  As a beginner I don't care about making a button work or anything, I want to see location data in a text box - that would be a better intro example app then hello,world.

If anyone would like to give me pointers on how to deal with different data types in Android that will be helpful, but honestly I posted this to hear reasons why data conversion have to be such a headache.

Thanks all!

Comment: From the Location class (And about every other class known to man): `toString()
Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object.`

Comment: Do you have any experience with Java? If not I strongly suggest you start there to get a good grasp on Object Oriented Design principles. Head First Java is a great book for beginners

Comment: How does `Location.getLatitude()` not work? What do you expect it to return vs. what it actually returns?

Comment: +1 to what @Otra said, `Location.toString` is actually [well written](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/location/Location.java#Location.toString%28%29) instead of the usual `Location@ab165d` fun.

Comment: Location.getLatitude() and Location.toString() do not work at all.  It compiles but crashes.  I don't know how to debug so that won't get me anywhere.

Comment: `It compiles but crashes.` @user961404 I can almost guarantee you, your error is not with these two methods. It probably a problem earlier, either with the previous code or permissions but unless you post your code here (and your manifest.xml), we have no way of helping you. Although if you do not know how to debug, then perhaps getting a user's location is not where you want to start your venture into programming.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  I am giving up the project, Java and OOP is not my thing.  Back to microcontrollers and asm for me.

Comment: Don't be frustrated. It seems to me that you just wanted too much at once. Start with the basics and work your way up. Afterall you are interested in this (why else would you try it?) and you can learn something. That's great! And you are not in a hurry, take your time. I know that everything looks easy from the outside, some people seem to spit great apps out on a single night. Believe me, it's work and  takes patience. Java people probably feel the same way when they see a full-fledged ASM app. Programming is frustrating at times. Take a small break and get some air - don't run away. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Java is Object Oriented Language, and Android API is based on OOP principles. And it's not problem - it's provide benefits to you. For example, your Location can provide too much information and methods on them. Look at the API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html
API provides access to attitude, latitude, longitude, etc. You can try to call toString() methods for debug or logging purposes if you want to look stringified presentation for all these fields. But it's not good way for any other purposes.

Comment: Thanks adbmob.  I can't get toString() to work at all, maybe the DDMS data isn't getting to the VM or something

Comment: How are you printing the `String`?

Comment: @CheJami - many different ways.  This issue is with 3 different example apps, all of which only run on the VM if the Location.getLatitude() and/or Location.toString() are commented out. Thanks.

Comment: @user961404 Did you add access privileges properties in AndroidManifest? 
Try these all: 
`android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
`android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS`
`android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am consuming data that is in a format I'm not a big fan of or contains more information than I need or the information needs to be "translated" in a more suitable form for my purpose, I create my own object model and a translation layer.  For example, when I consume a webservice that gives me json or xml data that I need to parse.  I just create a package (or namespace if I'm in the .Net world) called model and one called translators.  The model objects are the data exactly as my app wants it.  The translator classes take in the data and return my object.  The same would work for object-to-object translation and not just raw data like json and xml.  It takes very little time whatsoever, and when you write yourself helpers (for example, I have a JSONHelper class I created in Java for when I'm working with Android), you just copy it over from project to project making your workflow even faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic Java/OOP but this is also a question about mapping data-values. For example, you cannot simply attempt to calculate a value of two numbers that are not two numbers.

"6" (a string) does not equal the number value of 6 unless you tell the class to recognize that.

using bastardized Java/C#

```
String x = new String ("6");
int xi = 6;

return !x.equals( xi)// would actually fail
```

instead

```
return xi == Integer.parseInt(x);
```

So each part of the app and class needs to be able to understand what you are passing as parameters. Get that book Tim recommends or look up some of the various Java tutorials on the Oracle website (or on the web).

Comment: You right. This is not just about Java/OOP. This is also about Static Typed Languages vs Dynamic Typed Languages. 6 != "6" in Static Typed Languages at all. You need convert it manually to explain your motivation exactly. It's power of Static Typed Languages where you not making some types of errors. But for some other tasks more acceptable another behavior and Dynamic Typed Languages more acceptable.